# How can I set functions on a class dynamically in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a base class blah with functions a and b.

I want to extend (or create instances) of this class that may have function a or b (or both), such that if I create `BaseClassWithA` and I try to call `instance.b()` I will get a compilation error.

Specifically, this is for a Base CRUD Api, where I will extend it with various specific API instances, for example a 'UsersAPI'. Let's assume that the Users API might only have 'GET' as an allowed method. So if I/another developer goes to invoke `UsersAPI.delete`, they'll get a compilation error.

Here is an example of the Base API class:

```
export class CRUDBaseAPI<T extends ApiBaseType> {

    constructor(
        protected apiConfig: ApiConfig,
        protected http: HttpClient,
        protected errorService: ErrorService,
        protected allowedMethods: Method[] = ['get', 'update','delete'],
        protected httpConfig?: HttpConfiguration,
    ) {
    }

    public get(entity: T, httpConfig?: HttpConfiguration): Promise<T> {
        return this.http.get<T>(`${this.apiConfig.url}/${entity.id}`, this.getFullHttpConfiguration(httpConfig)).toPromise()
            .then(returnData)
            .catch(this.handleError(`Unable to retrieve ${this.apiConfig.entityName} record.`));
    }


    public update(entity: T, httpConfig?: HttpConfiguration): Promise<T> {
        return this.http.post(`${this.apiConfig.url}/${entity.id}`, entity, this.getFullHttpConfiguration(httpConfig)).toPromise()
            .then(returnData)
            .catch(this.handleError(`Unable to update ${this.apiConfig.entityName} record.`));
    }

    public delete(entity: T, httpConfig?: HttpConfiguration): Promise<T> {
        // TODO open confirm modal here and delete only if user confirms
        return this.http.delete(`${this.apiConfig.url}/${entity.id}`, this.getFullHttpConfiguration(httpConfig)).toPromise()
            .then(returnData)
            .catch(this.handleError(`Unable to delete ${this.apiConfig.entityName} record.`));
    }
}

function returnData(httpResponse: any) {
    return httpResponse;
}
```

Comment: i think mixins (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) is the feature you are looking for.

Comment: Mixins would also work.  That handbook page is out of date; documentation of the currently preferred approach is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#support-for-mix-in-classes).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something else. You can implement some sort of middleware. For example:

```
public delete(entity: T, httpConfig?: HttpConfiguration): Promise<T> {
    // the userService can hold the logged user that has a permissions array from database of whatever storage service you are using
    let canAccess = this.authService.loggedUser.permissions.includes('user.delete');
    if(!canAccess){
        // show a toaster or an 'access denied' error.
    }
}
```

And yes, you have to write those lines in every method. But you can extract it in the service like so:

```
class AuthService{
    authorize(permission){
       let canAccess = this.loggedUser.permissions.includes(permission);
        if(!canAccess){
            throw new Error('Access denied!'); // you can intercept this Error and display it to the user
        }
    }
}

export class UserAPI<T extends ApiBaseType> {

    public delete(entity: T, httpConfig?: HttpConfiguration): Promise<T> {
        this.authService.authorize('user.delete')
        // your processing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `get`, `update`, and `delete` methods protected in `CRUDBaseAPI` and then in each subclass, override the methods you want to be public with trivial wrappers that just call the super methods.